# Issue with reg expressions & routes in Codeigniter

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-2

I am having an issue using the routes in Codeigniter and my expressions

I have a URL like follows (for a offers page):

```
www.site.com/company/offers/view/newsarticle/219
```

and a route like follows:

```
$route['([a-z0-9_-]+)/offers/view/([a-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)'] = "offers/view/$1/$2/$3";
```

I have the above route setup so if should go to the offers controller, and the view function and pass the 3 parameters (company, newsarticle, 219)

It works all fine however if the 4th uri segment contains and '-' it breaks and gives me a 404 page
eg

This works

```
www.site.com/company/offers/view/newsarticle/219
```

But this doesn't

```
www.site.com/company/offers/view/news-article/219
```

Can anyone explain what I've done wrong with the expressions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression doesn't allow a hyphen character

```
([a-z0-9_-]+)/offers/view/([a-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)
```

Should be

```
([a-z0-9_-]+)/offers/view/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]+)
```

Note the `\-` in the `[a-z0-9\-]`. The `\` character escapes the hyphen to tell the expression engine that it's not a range operator.

Comment: cheers ben! such a noob mistake i know thanks for pointing out my error :)

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help.